# Rolling sum and mean in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have this input df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,'B','A',1,0], [1,'B','C',0,0], [2,'A','B',3,2],[3,'A','B',5,2],[4,'A','C',2,1],[5,'B','A',0,1],[6,'C','B',5,5]], columns=['events','Runner 1','Runner 2','dist_R1','dist_R2'])
print(df)
```

and i'd like to add 4 more rolling calculated columns as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,'B','A',1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,'B','C',0,0,1,0,1,0], [2,'A','B',3,2,0,1,0,0.5],[3,'A','B',5,2,3,3,2,1],[4,'A','C',2,1,8,0,2.67,0],[5,'B','A',0,1,5,10,1.25,2.5],[6,'C','B',5,5,1,5,0.5,1]], columns=['events','Runner 1','Runner 2','dist_R1','dist_R2','sum_dist_last_2_by_R1','sum dist last 2 by R2','mean dist last 2 by R1','mean dist last 2 by R2'])
print(df)
```

(sorry, but i'm learning how to format a df in StackOverflow)

I want to calculate last 4 columns.
In details i need to now at the star of the event "n" the sum and the mean km that Runner 1 and Runner 2 completed during the last two events they joined between thost from event 0 to n-1.
I think is quite challenging.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance,
M

Comment: It would be of tremendous help if you named your columns and rows, and explain your task based on that.

Comment: Your question ist unclear to me. Consider Nicolas' comment on formatting your dataframe in a readable way and show us your desired output.That should help you get more valuable replies

Comment: Tito, please, send a link in which is described how to format. G

Comment: I'm really sorry Nicolas, as I wrote in the post i'm learning how to format a df in StackOverflow.

Comment: Anyway names of columns are reported in an uncorrect way before data. They are: events,     Runner 1/2 (= name of the runner1/2),     dist_R1/2 (= distance ran from R1/2 during the event),             tot dist_R1/2 for last 2 events performed (= total distance ran by R1/2 in previous last 2 events they attended ),           mean dist_R1/2 for last 2 events performed (= mean distance ran by R1/2 in previous last 2 events they attended)

Comment: I'd like to know how to calculate last 4 columns. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote "rolling", but as a matter of fact it is a "very special type"
of rolling calculation (including only rows for runners from the current
row), so you can not use "pandasonic" *rolling* functions.
Instead you should compute the result other way.

Start from preparatory computation:

1. Generate 2 auxiliary DataFrames - results for runner 1 and runner 2:

   ```
   wrk1 = df[['events', 'Runner 1', 'dist_R1']]
   wrk1.columns = ['events', 'Runner', 'dist']
   wrk2 = df[['events', 'Runner 2', 'dist_R2']]
   wrk2.columns = ['events', 'Runner', 'dist']
   ```
2. Concatenate them, getting *wrk* DataFrame and delete 2 previous DataFrames:

   ```
   wrk = pd.concat([wrk1, wrk2]).sort_values('events')
   del wrk1, wrk2
   ```

Then define 2 following functions:

1. Get statistisc (sum and mean) for the given runner (*rnr*),
   from 2 last events before the given event (*ev*):

   ```
   def getStat(rnr, ev):
       res = wrk.query('Runner == @rnr and events < @ev').dist.iloc[-2:]
       return res.sum(), res.mean()
   ```
2. Get additional columns for the current row:

   ```
   def getAddCols(row):
       td_r1, md_r1 = getStat(row['Runner 1'], row.events)
       td_r2, md_r2 = getStat(row['Runner 2'], row.events)
       return pd.Series([td_r1, td_r2, md_r1, md_r2],
           index=['tot dist_R1', 'tot dist_R2', 'mean dist_R1', 'mean dist_R2'])
   ```

And to get the result, run:

```
df.join(df.apply(getAddCols, axis=1).fillna(0))\
    .astype({'tot dist_R1': int, 'tot dist_R2': int})
```

Note that a *Series* returned by *getAddCols* contains some *float* values,
so all 4 new columns are coerced to *float*.
To convert both *total* columns back to *int*, the last step (*astype*)
is needed.

The detailed results are a bit different from what you wrote in your post,
but I assume that you failed in your computation (in some cases).

Comment: Absolutely perfect even if, as a beginner coming from excel, i though it would be a little easier and less complicated. Anyway thank you so much, it works perfectly. You are right i was wrong in my computation. i added the -2 variation at the end because it is what i was looking for. Many thanks again, G

Comment: what if my event is the index column? (maybe my input data was not so well formatted) i'm trying to use "sort_index()", but how to modify the query line?

Comment: Rather call *reset_index* to convert *events* to a "regular" column. It will be a **single** modification instead of reworking the whole solution.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo...can you suggest me please where to put the inplace=true condition?

Comment: How to accept: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Where to put "inplace" - as a parameter of the instruction in question. But remember that then this instruction doesn't return any result. So if previously you saved the result of this instruction somewhere, you must change the progran logic.

Comment: Thanks, instead of inplace i just added df=df.join(df.apply(getAddCols, axis=1).fillna(0))\.astype({'tot dist_R1': int, 'tot dist_R2': int}) and solved my problem.
Now i'm going to accept following your suggestion. G,